# What's the right crontab entry for running cv?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get cron to run cv.

Putting this in crontab:

*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --user=harrumph

produces...

Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configurations may interfere. To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.

The correct path to civicrm.settings.php is

/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

SO...

How am I supposed to use EXPORT in crontab so as to point cv to where it should be looking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--cwd` option for `cv` to set a current working directory:

`*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/cv --cwd=/var/www/html/ api job.execute --user=harrumph`

Comment: Problem there is, this produces an error   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--cwd" option does not exist.

Comment: Do you happen to have an older version of cv? The option was added somewhat recently: https://github.com/civicrm/cv/pull/38

Answer (score 0):

Only path, not php-file nor webroot:

*/5 * * * * cv api job.execute --user=harrumph --cwd=/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm